# AWS outbound load balancing with health checks to multiple service providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer

I current have a AWS hosted service which makes http requests to an external service provider. I want to add some backup in case the external service provider goes down (which has happened).

Does AWS have a load balancer suitable for balancing outbound connections which also balances based on some health checks.

My idea is that if my primary provider goes down or fails some other health checks we will fail over to some backup endpoints which are from other providers.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Load Balancers does not support failover routing per se.

You can instead use [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/?nc1=h_ls), if it fits with your use case, with a [failover routing policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-failover.html)

Comment: This is almost suitable, however my different endpoints have different paths. So any solution would need to be able to route the failover to a completely different URL, not just a new IP address resolution.

Comment: A complete, and external, new route is not suitable but you can easily achieve it with  a proxy mapping using the API Gateway.